Не работает goto в cmd
В моём коде есть строки:
echo File wasn't found
echo 1.create file
echo 2.go to menu
choice /c 12 /n
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :create
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :menu

Метка :menu присутствует в самом начале, но программа завершается, игнорируя этот факт. Этот код стоит в самом конце кода в одном огромном if. Метки :create не существует, т. к. я только начал работу над проектом. Ос: Windows 10 Home.

IF /? должен помочь, по идее..

Проверка, какова логика команды, должна помочь? Я или чего-то не понимаю, или это вообще никак не связано с проблемой. По идее, справка есть и на сайте майкрософта.

Угу, не понимаешь. В строке if %errorlevel%==2 ты проверяешь на ошибку выполнение строки if %errorlevel%==1, а вовсе даже не choice. Код ошибки без его сброса и перезаписи проверяется немного другим образом - и указанная мной команда расскажет, как именно.

Вместо
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :create
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :menu

примените
if %errorlevel%==1 goto create
if %errorlevel%==2 goto menu

т.е. никакое двоеточие в команде goto.
